# Rails Spreadsheet Gem From HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, https, spreadsheet

Im using the Rails Roo Gem.  I want to be able to get a .xls file from a https url.  How can I do this.
I can easily switch to another gem such as Spreadsheet if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving a file is not the responsibility of your spreadsheet gem, but there are a number of ways to get things like that. The easiest is to use `open-uri`, and the most robust is to use the `curb` gem which is a wrapper around libcurl.

Simple example:

```
require 'open-uri'

spreadsheet = open('https://example.com/spreadsheet.xls').read
```

The `curb` gem has a pile of additional options that make this statement more tolerant of bad network connections and invalid SSL certificates, among other things. It can also be used to POST back a modified spreadsheet if that's a requirement.

Comment: Good example; however, Roo does have this capability built in.  It just only checks for "http://".  I just had to modify the gems source a bit.